# Passing variables to an included file

Tags: php, oop, include

I have a template class which goes like this:

```
class Template{
public $pageTitle = "";
public function __construct($pageTitle){
    $this->pageTitle = $pageTitle;
}

public function display(){
    include "/includes/head.php";
    include "/includes/body.php";
}
}
```

Now, I'm used to Java's workings but I don't understand why I'm getting an undefined variable ($pageTitle) error. The included files need to be able to access that variable. I know it's going to be very simple but I actually haven't found out why. 
What do I need to do to allow includes to see this variable?

Comment: Have you initiated your class in those files OR after creating the class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The includes will also have to use `$this->pageTitle`. Effectively, the `include` makes them part of the method body.

Answer (score 3):

The included file lives in the same scope as your object. So you need to call:

```
$this->pageTitle
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do the whole **$this->**, you can do something like the following... The extract function will extract the array $this->data into variables with names respective to the key/index of each item. So now you will be able to do **echo $pageTitle;**

```
class Template{
   public $data = Array();

   public function __construct($pageTitle){
        $this->data['pageTitle'] = $pageTitle;
   }

   public function display(){
        extract($this->data);
        include "/includes/head.php";
        include "/includes/body.php";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scope is a little different in PHP than in java.
For your specific case you need

```
$this->pageTitle
```

To access a variable declared outside the class, you'll need to make it global

```
global $myVar;
```

Comment: I didn't use globals inside the class... I was just pointing out a fact... geez people really abuse the downvote button, don't they?